# How do I get the value of this xml?

Tags: javascript, xml

I have the following xml:

```
<Order>
  <size width="16.5" height="19.5">
    <width>16.5</width>
    <height>19.5</height>
  </size>
  ...
</Order>
```

I have tried the following to get the value of width/height:

```
width = parseFloat(doc.getElementsByTagName('width')[0].innerHTML);
height = parseFloat(doc.getElementsByTagName('height')[0].innerHTML);
```

However in the default Android browser and IE, I get the following when I alert the width: NaN. This code works fine in Chrome.

Comment: Since it's an XML document, the elements probably don't have an `innerHTML` property.

Comment: If not, then what would I use instead to get the values?

Comment: Have you tried `.text`?

Comment: I just did and I get the same issue.

Comment: Ah, it should be `.textContent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have XML, not just HTML you should use `childNodes` and `nodeValue`:

```
width = parseFloat(doc.getElementsByTagName('width')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```

Comment: I think in some versions of IE, childNodes will have three elements, second being text one. So it's better to write something like this:
`var childNodes=doc.getElementsByTagName('width')[0].childNodes;`
`childNodes[parseInt(childNodes.length/2)].nodeValue`